# Why does screen height of Nexus 5 doesn't feet to specs?

Tags: android, android-studio, dpi

1) Create empty layout resource
2) Open it in Android Studio (2.2.2)
3) Set background colour 
4) Set height as 550dp
5) set Nexus 5 as device for preview

You will see that layout has a tiny gap with the screen.
So the actual height of layout is about 570dp
**Screen height = status bar height + the layout height = 24 + 570 = 594dp**
**In specs Nexus 5 has 640dp**

WTF?

[image]

**Also it seems that I haven't toolbar.** 
I added a view to relative layout with property of align parenttop and it was placed at the top right under status bar.

[image]

Comment: toolbar  / body / navbar   ... will the hierarchy viewer let u turn on pixel level metrics for what is being rendered on the device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Count in the navigation bar's height which is 48dp according to [this xml](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/res/res/values/dimens.xml).

```
<!-- Height of the bottom navigation / system bar. -->
<dimen name="navigation_bar_height">48dp</dimen>
<dimen name="navigation_bar_height_landscape">48dp</dimen>
```

Comment: See it seems that I haven't toolbar, any other ideas?

Comment: Not toolbar, navigation bar. It's the bottom of the screen, the navigation buttons, usually: back, home, task manager.

Comment: I can't provide a screenshot but I am sure that I haven't navigation bar too. If I have it it would be visible in preview below the status bar, but I placed a view right under the status

Comment: Uh sorry now I understood :)